# Unity 2D Problem: Tilemap Tearing ONLY in Scene View

Tags: unity, sprites, tilemap

Facing an annoying problem with unity, googled to no avail. Basically I was having tilemap tearing so I created a sprite default material with pixel snap on. This fixed the tearing when running the game, but caused massive tearing in just my scene view. This does not affect gameplay but is very annoying when trying to create backgrounds and stuff.

Pic of scene view: https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/810052982220652577/836562483883016192/tilemaptearing.PNG

[My problem is identical to the one asked in this thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60131313/experiencing-a-strange-tile-rendering-bug-in-unitys-scene-view) but the solution this person came up with was to not use pixel snapping, but I need that to prevent tearing in the actual game. Anyone know what could be causing this and how could I fix?

Edit: Current version 2019.5.0a5, currently updating to most recent version

Comment: What version of Unity are you using?

Comment: I am using 2019.3.0a5

Comment: Why are you using an alpha release from almost 2 years ago? You should upgrade to the latest version of Unity 2019.4 LTS. These tilemap issues are likely to be bugs that were fixed in newer versions of Unity.

Comment: Alright, I'm updating now. Is there a reason I should update to 2019.4 LTS instead of the latest version 2020.3.5f1?

Comment: Have you considered [replacing this shader in the scene view](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneView.SetSceneViewShaderReplace.html) or detecting in your shader whether you're rendering with the scene view camera and shortcutting the pixel snap logic?

Comment: @DavidFleniken LTS (long-term support) releases (20xx.4.x) are considered the most stable, and I generally recommend using LTS releases unless you need a specific feature from a newer version of the engine. 2020 does have a lot of new features, so that's a decision you should make.

Comment: @Kevin Thank you! That's very helpful. Unity hub says that 2020.3.5f1 is LTS as well, so unless I'm being stupid I think that is the best choice for me. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @DavidFleniken D'oh! Previously, the LTS branch has always been 20xx.4; I forgot that for Unity 2020, the LTS branch is 2020.3. My bad!